# Network driver is playing up

Tags: networking, windows-8, drivers, sony-vaio

I have a sony vaio VGN-CR353 that originally came with windows vista installed. I had it upgrade to windows 7 and finally to windows 8. The problem is that something is wrong with my internet connection (some of the time not all of the time). When opening the browser, it would keep spinning for ever Connecting or Waiting on 'web-site', and sometimes it would take too long to open the page but it appears as text only with no layouts or images, and in case of youtube the video loads few seconds and stops.
I think this problem is more frequent when there's another PC connected to the same router or if my PC hasn't been restarted or shutdown in days.
When it happens I can't share anything so I thought it would be a driver issue, but the problem existed back when I had vista, I even replaced the router with no different results. Any Help Or Suggestions Would Be Very Much Appreciated..........Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was AVG all along. There is a video acceleration option that somehow goes wrong when I try to view a YouTube video, after which the browser will not load any other requested pages. So I disabled it and all seems well.